# Galaxy S3 and Galaxy S4 with layout-sw360dp

Tags: android, android-layout, galaxy

Kindly I want to know why Galaxy S3 and S4 get the images from this folder (drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi)??

all images seem very large for these devices !
also If I make these images smaller they will not be suitable for larger devices !
Please, what is the solution?

Comment: what other folders do you have?

Comment: drawable-sw360dp-hdpi
drawable-sw360dp-ldpi
drawable-sw360dp-mdpi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using layouts for 10 inch and 7 inch devices are layout-sw720dp and layout-sw600dp then you just create drawable-sw720dp and drawable-sw600dp, also in the case of high density for those xlarge and large screen devices then append the corresponding density to the drawable folder . For example use drawable-sw600dp-hdpi for high density 7 inch tablets like  ASUS MeMO Pad HD 7'. Now resource for large and xlarge are solved

Now Consider the drawable-sw360dp devices.

1. drawable-sw360dp/layout-sw360dp are for phablet devices like Note1,Note2, Micromax CanvasHD,S3.
2. The above mentioned devices are XHDPI devices. For using drawables either you can use drawable-xhdpi or  use drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi

Thus you can distinguish resources for s3,s4 from xlarge and large screen devices.

Note : S3 and s4 taking images from drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi because smallest width of those devices are 320dp. You can check the device display information by installing screen info app from the playstore.

[check screen info app  here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo)

Answer (score 0):

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It is based on the dpi

even now there is a xxhdpi folder or I may be wrong on that one??? Some one else to confirm that?